# Parsing XML document with namespace using logstash

Tags: xpath, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am trying to parse the following xml data using logstash.I am able to do it by removing the namespace from tags.But when I am trying it on the actual documents which is having namespace in it, its not able to parse the fields. Can someone help with the use of namespace or whether I am going wrong somewhere else?

```
<Book:Body>
    <Book:Head>
        <bookname>Book:Name</bookname>
            <ns:Hello xmlns:ns="www.example.com">
                <ns:BookDetails>
                    <ns:ID>123456</ns:ID>
                    <ns:Name>ABC</ns:Name>
                </ns:BookDetails>
        </ns:Hello xmlns:ns="www.example.com">
    </Book:Head>
</Book:Body>
```

Following is my config file:

```
multiline   {
                       pattern =>  "<Book:Body>"
                        what => "previous"
                        negate => "true"
            }

                xml {
                        store_xml => "false"
                        source => "message"
                        remove_namespaces => "true"

                        xpath =>[
                                "/Book/Book/BookDetails/ID/text()","ID",

                                "/Book/Book/BookDetails/Name/text()","Name"
                                ]


                    }

                mutate {
                        add_field => ["IDIndexed", "%{ID}"]
                        add_field => ["NameIndexed", "%{Name}"]
                        }
```

As it is not getting parsed, I am just getting %{ID} and %{Name} using mutate instead of getting their actual values.

Comment: Your XPaths don't seem to match your sample XML.  Given your sample, I would have expected to see: `/Body/Head/bookname/Hello/BookDetails/ID`.

Comment: Thanks a lot..It helped! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in xpath :
try this

```
xpath => [
 "/Body/head/Hello/BookD/BookDetails/ID/text()", "ID",
  "/Body/head/Hello/BookD/BookDetails/Name/text()", "Name",
    ]
```